# Paid position at a US lab

Tags: research-process, funding, independent-researcher, research-assistantship

Can one get paid while conducting research at a US university lab, without being a staff, student, visiting student, or a postdoctoral fellow? What are possible titles that are acceptable by grants? Assuming the grant sources are NSF and IARPA.

According to wikipedia, [visiting scholar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visiting_scholar) is a high level recognition. Is there an alternative for a paid researcher who does not hold a PhD and is not initially affiliated, but whose research is valuable to the lab?

Comment: What's the aversion to a staff position? Almost all universities have an hourly title that they can pay someone to do almost anything under. What's the relation to grant funding? Is the grant already awarded or are you trying to look your best in a grant application?

Comment: I believe the lab will have to use their grants in order to pay someone, so I was wondering if there are restriction as to the title, affiliation, or tasks of the person who will get paid from such grants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that most universities have different titles for different functionally similar positions, I wouldn't sweat it too much. The only places where things are different in my experience with NSF are for faculty and post docs. I know NSF has a rule about the total amount of time that a person can be funded (without explicit exception from the Program Officer) on an award (2 months), but these rules are generally only applied to faculty since they are expected to get 9 months of support from their institution. NSF also requires a [Postdoctoral Researcher Mentoring Plan](http://www.nsf.gov/pubs/policydocs/pappguide/nsf10_1/gpg_2.jsp#bfn28) for any proposal that will fund post docs. This is there to ensure that post docs have their careers promoted appropriately and that they learn appropriate collaboration methods.

That being said, you don't even have to work at a university to be paid under an NSF award. There are frequent subcontracting relationships created to send funding to other institutions including private companies and contractors.